# Debugging Visual Studio 2010/IE 8 - Unable to start program - Element not found

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-8

When trying to debug an MVC2 app in VS2010 using IE 8, 
I sometimes get the following error (port number changes).

> Unable to Start program 'http://localhost:55853/' 
>   Element not found

It is really difficult to find the problem as it seems to be totally random.
Has anyone else come across this problem?

Comment: The only way I can seem to get around this is by opening task manager and force quitting all iexplorer instances and all instances of the WebDev server.

Comment: Even that doesn't seem to work now. arghhhhh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools > Internet Options > Advanced 
Under the Browsing Section
--- Uncheck the "Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)

Answer (score 3):

if you had to add the DWORD TabProcGrowth to your registry in order to debug in VS2005 using IE8, you will need to delete that DWORD in order to debug in VS2010 using IE8.

Answer (score 0):

you can turn of dynamic port in project setting. By doing that, you can prevent starting multiple instance of asp.net developer server.

Answer (score 0):

Disable automatic crash recovery in IE via 'Internet Options' -> 'Advanced' -> 'Browsing'.