# Mysterious Error on Rebuilds C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am having an error pop-up on me every time my project requires a rebuild when it tries to run afterwards. However if i just run the project after this error it runs fine.

When I check the error list after this error box appears, it does not return any errors (which it should not since it isn't a build error) and the same goes for the output window.

[image: The Highly Descriptive Error Message]

This error is not a huge problem, but gets highly annoying at times. (having to build ... click ok on the error ... then run...) I would be very appreciative if someone could point me in a direction to get rid of this. I am not looking for a direct solution just maybe somewhere to start looking at.

Thanks

Edit:

I have also now tried my application on another computer and I do not receive the error. I also tried a repair on my vs2010 installation with no luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864520/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-cannot-find-the-file

Comment: There is supposed to be an error message following that line of text.  None there, that make it hard to diagnose.  Try starting another instance of VS, Tools + Attach to Process, pick devenv.exe.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown boxes.  Try it on another machine too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will give this a shot, and post about how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look around in the CSProj/solution file (perhaps a broken path or something), it seems odd that there isn't a project name or error description there.

If you have more than one project, try Solution Explorer > Right Click (project node) > Set as startup project.

Check the build and build events setting in the project properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems my paths are pointing to the correct loactions, and I only have one project in the Solution even so i tried  setting it as the start-up project with no luck. 

Also i had no special build events in my properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clean build or manually wiping out the bin folder. Hard to diagnose without more information.

Have you tried moving the copying the solution folder to another location and building / running from there? Maybe it will give you a better error?

Comment: hmm thanks for the suggestion, I had tried a clean and rebuild before and when moving my copying my project to an alternate location I received the same error

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly have an addin causing a problem.  If you use any I would turn them off long enough to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. From what i know the only plug-ins i have is Visual Assist and Ankh svn i tried disabling them without any changes. Also if i view the add-in manager it does not show anything.