# C++ Compiles fine but cannot debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file-not-found

Ok, let me be very clear so I don't have to repeat myself later on. Please read carefully, I'll try to be as concise as possible. I will put parts I want to stress in bold.

I am pretty good with C++, I am not a begginer. I made alot of projects and this is I think the second time it happens in 6 months.

Here's the problem, I started a console project that doesn't have a console, but an opengl window launched by the SDL library. I was having fun and all and **built and debugged** my project several times and **it was both building and running fine**.

Then, **out of the blue**, I built my project after some addition (shooting bullets, if you wanna know) and I wanted to test the addition. **it built fine (build succeed)**, but when I try to start debugging, it says that the .exe file was not found. It doesn't seem to create a .exe file.

Now here are some precisions you might wanna know:

- I didn't change project settings and it was running fine before.
- It has nothing to do with my bullet shooting, I mean it builds fine.
- My project has a main.cpp and a GLRect Class I made and a GameConstants.h file I made with game constants in it.
- I'm using Visual Studio 2010, I installed the SDL-1.2.15 library with the SDL_image add-on.
- I'm running on a Windows 8 64-bit laptop with the following specs:
  16GB Ram
  i7 ivy bridge processor 2.3GHz
  NVIDIA GTX 670M 3GB graphic card

*If you need more specs just ask*

- Origine is the name of my project.
- In C:...\Origine\Origine\Debug\ I have a lot of .tlog files.

Here's a build log, however it is in french...

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Origine, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2013-07-01 01:54:39.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\Origine.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\Origine.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.h(14): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'const double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.h(14): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'const double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.h(14): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'const double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.h(14): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'const double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\main.cpp(26): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'time_t' en 'unsigned int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\main.cpp(133): warning C4018: '<' : incompatibilité signed/unsigned
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\main.cpp(161): warning C4018: '<' : incompatibilité signed/unsigned
1>  GLRect.cpp
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.h(14): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'const double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.h(14): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'const double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.h(14): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'const double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.h(14): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'const double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(46): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(46): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(47): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(47): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(48): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(48): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(49): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(49): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(54): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(54): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(55): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(55): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(56): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(56): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(57): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(57): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'GLfloat', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(165): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>c:\users\alexandre\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jeux\origine\origine\glrect.cpp(165): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'int', perte possible de données
1>  Génération de code en cours...
1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: conflit entre la bibliothèque par défaut 'msvcrt.lib' et les autres bibliothèques ; utilisez /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Manifest:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\Origine2.exe.embed.manifest".
1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: conflit entre la bibliothèque par défaut 'msvcrt.lib' et les autres bibliothèques ; utilisez /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>  Origine.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Alexandre\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Jeux\Origine\Debug\Origine2.exe
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\Origine.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Debug\Origine.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.05
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `Ok, let me be very clear so I don't have to repeat myself later on.` -- You guys can't just understand it in one go!

Comment: Rebuild all, and if that doesn't work please include the build-log in your question.

Comment: Can u debug if you remove the new addition (shooting bullets)?

Comment: Writing protip: don't stress "out of the blue."

Comment: I rebuilt many times.

Comment: It cannot debug if I remove bullet shooting

Comment: It gives the impression that something messed up when building and now my project is somewhat screwed unless I do something...

Comment: @johnchen902 Looking at the log, the original text read "I will put parts I want to stress in caps, I'm not raging at my computer screen." and Alex helpfully (mercifully) changed the caps to bold.

Comment: It's too long for being in one comment

Comment: Oh and it's in french...

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there.  Make sure you highlight it and hit the `{}` button so it's correctly formatted.  I'm sure we can handle some french.  If not, Google translator is our friend.

Comment: Did you get it off BitTorrent?

Comment: @user2537827 You can either 1. Edit your question or 2. Provide an external link. About language... We can ask Google to translate.

Comment: Don't post code or logs or things like that in a comment, edit your question and add it there instead.

Comment: Done, lots of warnings, could it be that? I mean, warnings don't really matter, it's mostly type incompatibility (signed/unsigned), but I make sure no data loss occurs.

Comment: And btw, now that I think about it, it's strange that my build logs are in french since my IDE is in English...

Comment: @user2537827: Actually, warnings *do* matter, but not in this case. Could you check that you actually do have an "origine.exe" file somewhere? By default, it should be in you solution directory, under "Debug". If in doubt, you can use Windows' "Find..." or something.

Comment: In C\...\Origine\Origine\ I have no Origine or in this case Origine2.exe, I have .exe.embed.manifest,res and others but they all have suffix extensions after the .exe.

Comment: However when I went to C:\Origine\Debug\ (insted of C:\Origine\Origine\Debug) I had a .exe, but when I tried to execute it, it said "C\..\Origine\Origine\Debug\Origine.exe file not found" and it got automatically deleted.

Comment: You should really fix those warnings, as they can indicate undefined behavior. The most important things to fix is the linker conflicts. Also, can you please post the output from when you try to debug? If there is any then it could tell a lot too.

Comment: Sounds like your anti-virus is getting in the way. Could be a false positive from a recent update. Check your anti-virus logs and quarantine list.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Neither the warnings nor the link conflicts are causing his problems. Although fixing them is the Right Thing, it won't help here.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I was going to say the same thing!

Comment: @user2537827: Could you temporarily disable you antivirus and do a rebuild?

Comment: Nothing in the console, however here is what the pop-up message says:

And notice how this message is bilingual...
Unable to start program 'C:\...\Origine\Debug\Origine2.exe'

Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program. Cannot find the file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864520/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-cannot-find-the-file) and [Error Message:Unable to run program , the specified file is not found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16301043)

Comment: Beyond the actual problem, the random bilingual error messages that you're getting are very strange. I suspect something is wrong with your operating system and/or Visual Studio installation. As others have mentioned, pirating software from BitTorrent subjects you to problems like this. Remember that Visual Studio Express is [a free download](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-2010-express).

Comment: OMG Thank you! Yea it was Avast the problem and I am surprised I didn't think about it, because I am usually very good at debugging my code and the one of others as well. What should've made me suspect avast is when the .exe file I had got deleted without warning

Now, could you tell me  how to make avast stop blocking it please? And how can I mark this question as resolved?

Comment: You can and are encouraged to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) when you find the answer. There is a system-imposed delay before you can accept your own answer, but eventually you will be able to do so, which marks the question as "resolved".

Comment: Thanks guys, one last thing, even if I suppose it's not good, but what does the -3 means next to my question?

Comment: The -3 means your question was downvoted. And BTW: replace Avast, it creates a lot of strange problems for many customers.

Comment: And replace it with what?

Comment: @user2537827: Comodo Internet Security. Also, that -3 means at least 3 people found your question to be useless, irrelevant or otherwise unsuitable for SO.

Comment: The bilingual error message can happen when the OS is in french and the IDE in english. If both are english, then you have a bigger problem. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your anti-virus software. The obvious symptom is that the file is deleted when you immediately attempt to start it manually (and that you commented it was the problem). Refer to your anti-virus documentation on how to add an exception to the directory or file.

Comment: Also consider configuring your antivirus to do something *slightly* more sane than an automatic delete, like quarantine the file.

Comment: Migrate to linux or mac osx and compile in a VM.

Comment: And you probably don't want your antivirus checking the executables you are building anyways, since it only slows down your builds (only a factor for large projects.) Consider adding your working directories or your project trees to the "exclusion" list of your antivirus.