# The system cannot find the file specified. in Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error with these lines of code:

```
include <iostream>

int main()
    {

        cout << "Hello World" >>;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

"The system cannot find the file specified"

[image]

Comment: you've got 'include' in a line on its own. You should have `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Is pause an external command or a builtin in cmd.exe

Comment: @MikeVine Was a formatting problem, although `#` is still missing.

Comment: Its not an executable on my win-box

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system cannot find the file specified usually means the build failed (which it will for your code as you're missing a `#` infront of `include`, you have a stray `>>` at the end of your `cout` line and you need `std::` infront of cout) but you have the 'run anyway' option checked which means it runs an executable that doesn't exist. Hit F7 to just do a build and make sure it says '0 errors' before you try running it.

Code which builds and runs:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World";
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code should be :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Or maybe :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Just a quick note: I have deleted the system command, because I heard it's not a good practice to use it. (but of course, you can add it for this kind of program)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Unfortunately I have this error

on my visual studio "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: do you mean that you still have the "The system cannot find the file specified" error with my code or Mike's code ? Can you copy/paste the complete error message (if available) ? And can you make sure that you build a **Console** project ?

Comment: The whole error message should be in the "Output" view, with the "Show input from" combobox selected on "Build".

If you don't know how to know if you are building a console project, just create another one with the new code. It will be simpler.

Comment: just added screenshot

Comment: Take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864520/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-cannot-find-the-file The top most answer may resolve your problem. (or its comments)

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem and this fixed it:

You should add:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64`    *for 64 bit system*

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib`        *for 32 bit system*

in `Property Manager`>`Linker`>`General`>`Additional Library Directories`

Answer (score 1):

Another take on this that hasn't been mentioned here is that, when in debug, the project may *build*, but it won't *run*, giving the error message displayed in the question.

If this is the case, another option to look at is the output file versus the target file. These should match.

A quick way to check the output file is to go to the project's property pages, then go to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General (In VS 2013 - exact path may vary depending on IDE version).

There is an "Output File" setting. If it is not `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`, then you may run into issues.

This is also discussed in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36110671/2658159).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error because of two things.

1. I opened an empty project
2. I didn't add #include "stdafx.h"

It ran successfully on the win 32 console.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not compiled it. Click 'Project > compile'. Then, either click 'start debugging', or 'start without debugging'.

Comment: there is no compile option

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue after deleting folder where I was trying to add the file in Visual Studio. Deleted folder from window explorer also. After doing all this, successfully able to add folder and file.