# Unable to run hello world in Visual Studio Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've just installed Visual Studio community edition from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

But it seems I cannot get hello world to run.

I create a new "Console Application" and Module1.vb is created.

I then created a .cs file and add following code :

```
using System;

    // Hello1.cs
    public class Hello1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
```

But how do I run this code ?

When I attempt "Run to Cursor" gives error "Cannot run to specified location"

Comment: did you create a visual basic project instead of a c# project?

Comment: You created the wrong type of project if you had a .vb file...

Comment: `Module1.vb is created.` of course he did.

Comment: This MSDN link covers everything you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864520/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-cannot-find-the-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a C# project instead of a Visual Basic one. You should have a `Program.cs` file generated that you will then be able to modify and add to.