# Unable to debug Windows Store App ... A component dll failed to load. VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have my code working and I can compile my app and run it for Windows Desktop in my local machine and simulator.
Also I can run it in the Mobile Emulator 10.10240.
So my app works just fine.

But just recently (I don't know what I did wrong), I got the following error whenever I set it to ARM and deploy it to my physical phone.

**UPDATE:** The app is getting installed, but the debugger just doesn't work

And of Course developer mode is set up and everything is ready and good to go. Remeber I have done this before, but something went bad with the debugger,

How can I debug my app using my phone again?

[image: Can't run my app on the phone]

**UDPATE2.** These are all the steps that I did:

- In VS2015 delete .suo which is in the hidden vs folder of the project from this website: [Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program. Cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864520/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-cannot-find-the-file)
- I also tried the "resolutions" in this one: https://superuser.com/questions/627871/visual-studio-2012-component-dll-failed-to-load-unable-to-start-program

And finally despite all what I wanted I ended up reinstalling Windows 10 RS SDK, but if someone else runs into this trouble and doesn't want to do the repair or reinstalling I suggest doing the first two and also if you are working in a shard project with something like git, make sure that you have the last version of the SDK of everything your other team members are using (I believe that was my problem)

Comment: Is you phone in developer mode?

Comment: Seems your VS is somehow broken, try to repair it, if that doesn't work, try reinstall vs2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem today.  I tried several things but finally decided to apply all of the available Visual Studio Updates.  That seems to have solved this problem.  Hope that helps you.

Comment: Can you point out what updates? I don't have any "real" updates to be done

Comment: In the end I think you were kind of right. And after doing the update to Red Stone SDK things went back to normal.